# How can I get 100 to 200 words from HTML without affecting HTML tags using Nodejs or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting data from my database and send in mail, data comes with HTML tags. Now problem is I want to display only 100 letters in mail. But when I remove some words HTML tags also remove and it will destroy whole Output. Please guide me how can I achieve this.

**Sample Output From Database**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="snip">We are looking for physically fit individuals to fill general labour requirements by partnering with a truck driver. Your help is needed to load/unload the truck at the various job sites.
<b>Skills required: </b>
- comfortable with physical exertion and lifting minimum of 50lbs
- works well on a team but trusted to work independently
- reliable, self-motivated and committed to high standards of quality
- able to read and understand work instructions
<b>Specific requirements: </b>
- in good physical condition
- must have own safety footwear
- reliable transportation to ensure punctual and consistent attendance
If you meet the qualifications listed above, submit your resume in MS Word format via the link below.
<i>Previously employed with The Staffing Connection? Please contact our office to confirm your continued availability for these upcoming positions.</i></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Required**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="snip">We are looking for physically fit individuals to fill general labour requirements by partnering with a truck driver. Your help is needed to load/unload the truck at the various job sites.
<b>Skills required: </b>
- comfortable with physical exertion and lifting minimum of 50lbs
- works well on a team but trusted to work independently
- reliable, self-motivated and committed to high standards of quality
- able to read and understand work instructions
<b></b>
<i></i></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I use something like `'Hiya how are you'.substring(0,8);`

Comment: Do you want just text with no markup at all? Or you want to preserve the HTML but limit it to the first 100 characters of text? What environment is your code running in? (Browser? Node?)

Comment: @rayhatfield i want to preserve HTML and i use Node

Comment: Hello, [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)!  What do you hope to accomplish by displaying only 100 letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cat use `cheerio` libary for its:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const input = `
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="snip">We are looking for physically fit individuals to fill general labour requirements by partnering with a truck driver. Your help is needed to load/unload the truck at the various job sites.
<b>Skills required: </b>
- comfortable with physical exertion and lifting minimum of 50lbs
- works well on a team but trusted to work independently
- reliable, self-motivated and committed to high standards of quality
- able to read and understand work instructions
<b>Specific requirements: </b>
- in good physical condition
- must have own safety footwear
- reliable transportation to ensure punctual and consistent attendance
If you meet the qualifications listed above, submit your resume in MS Word format via the link below.
<i>Previously employed with The Staffing Connection? Please contact our office to confirm your continued availability for these upcoming positions.</i></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
`;

const result = cheerio.load(input.substring(0, 200), { xmlMode: true });

console.log(result.html());
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wr4fez?file=index.js

Comment: I didn't see this comment when post answer=)

Comment: I change my solution for node.js and new conditions.